# How to become a ruby on rails intermediate/master developer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I started learning  ruby on rails about 3 month ago. I' ve follow several tutorial on twitter clone and i'm on my way to finish the Ruby on rails tutorial by micheal hartl and was wondering  how do i make sure to push for the next level. My goal is to be able to make great app that can deal the actual web standard . There is a lot of content to learn rails for beginner  but i would like to get blog, tutorial ,books or any other link for those how want to push there knowledge on the framework forward . Thank you .

I think that every body answer is important to that question so i' not gonna validate any answer .by respect for everybody . but thanks a lot and keep adding answer and feedback .

Comment: 1.: experience 2.: experience 3.: experience http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 5):

The short answer would be: "Practice, Practice, Practice".

Start reading code of gems you've using. You will pleasantly surprised that you can find answers for many your questions by diving into the code.

Along with the practice you should always be informed about news, tips, tricks and new features. So I would recommend you subscribe to [RubyWeekly](http://rubyweekly.com/) unless you already subscribed. Read articles about Ruby on Rails and play with the code samples you've read from these articles.

I've also recommend you to become involved with TDD/BDD it really changes the thinking about how writing code.

Follow the screen casts. You probably know about [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/). I've also recommend you to subscribe on [Destroy All Software](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts) it's cost $9 per month but it worth it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a lot of free books about programming (includes ruby, sql, design patterns and others): http://programming-motherfucker.com/become.html

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation.
In order to read:

1. [http://www.amazon.com/Eloquent-Ruby-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321584104](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104)
2. [http://www.amazon.com/Rails-Way-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Ruby/dp/0321601661](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601661)
3. [http://www.amazon.com/Rails-AntiPatterns-Refactoring-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321604814](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321604814)
4. [http://www.amazon.com/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Pros/dp/1934356476](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476)